# httpClient to httpClient5

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to upgrade my Spring Boot project from Boot 2.7 to 3.1.
At the same time I am migrating some codes using httpclient to hc client5.

Below is the code.

```kotlin
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig

class Boot2 {
    fun springBoot2() {
        val requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(1)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3)
            .build()
    }
}
```

I tried to convert the code to

```kotlin
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig
import org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout

class Boot3 {
    fun springBoot3() {
        val requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(1L))
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(3L))
            .build()
    }
}
```

The code using hc client 5 seems wrong. This is the message I got:
`Cannot access class 'org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`
[image]

I cannot understand how RequestConfig.builder cannot access to core5.util.Timeout. I thought they are from the same dependency (maven "org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1") but seems like I am wrong.

What would be a better way for this situation? This is my first time using hc client5 and I am a bit confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The site has many rules regarding how a question should be written. One such rules is that error messages and code must always be placed as text in the question, never an image.